# How can I use the Exclusions option to exclude all $x$ values of the form $\pi/2 + \pi n$?

Tags: plotting

Intuitively, I'm trying to do the following:

```
Plot[Tan[x], {x, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}, Exclusions -> {(* x = Pi/2 + Pi n *)}]
```

and I want to know what I should replace the comment with to get the desired effect.

Comment: does `Exclusions -> Automatic` give the desired result?

Comment: Would `Plot[Tan[x], {x, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}, Exclusions -> Range[-7/2Pi,4Pi,Pi]]` do what you want?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not actually trying to plot this. It's just an example to illustrate something I want to learn how to do with the `Exclusions` option.

Comment: @MarcoB Yes, thank you!

Comment: `Plot[Tan[x], {x, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}, Exclusions -> Table[Pi/2 +Pi*n, {n, -4, 3}]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Plot[Tan[x], {x, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}, 
 Exclusions -> {Mod[x, Pi] == Pi/2}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

You can also list the points to be excluded using `Exclusions -> Pi/2 + Range[-10, 10] Pi`:

```
Plot[Tan[x], {x, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}, 
 Exclusions -> Pi/2 + Range[-10, 10] Pi, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> Red]
```

> same picture

Answer (score 2):

There is `FunctionDiscontinuities[]` since V12.2 (and also `FunctionSingularities[]` — for the difference I suggest trying them on `Abs[x]` or `Abs[Tan[x]]`), which can be used to construct exclusions based on another function:

```
Plot[Sec[x], {x, -4 Pi, 4 Pi},
 Exclusions -> {FunctionDiscontinuities[Tan[x], x]},
 ExclusionsStyle -> {Dashed, Red} (* {line, point} styles *)
 ]
```

[image]

You can mark the discontinuities of one function on the graph of another:

```
Plot[x^2, {x, -4 Pi, 4 Pi},
 Exclusions -> {FunctionDiscontinuities[Tan[x], x]},
 ExclusionsStyle -> {Dashed, Red}]
```

[image]

Comment: ...prompted by the comment, "... something I want to learn how to do with the `Exclusions` option."